# Create one-to-one model record, or update if it already exists, in this Django view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

`UserComputedInfo` model has a one-to-one relationship with `CustomUser` model.
I want to update or create a record in `UserComputedInfo` during a form update to `CustomUser`. I managed to create/update a record in views.py

Here is the code;

```
from .models import UserComputedInfo 

def profile(request, username):
        if request.method == "POST":
            user = request.user
            form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
            if form.is_valid():
                user_form = form.save()
                # How to save post_code to copy_input in UserComputedInfo model
                user_computed_info_instance = UserComputedInfo(user_id=user.id)
                user_computed_info_instance.copy_input = 1.18 # or whatever value to be assigned
                user_computed_info_instance.save()
    
                messages.success(request, f'{user_form.username}, Your profile has been updated!')
                return redirect("profile", user_form.username)
    
        return redirect("homepage")
```

This is a follow-up question to a flawed answer I posted to my own past question.
[Save values into another database table with one-to-one relationship in Django during form update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73727483/save-values-into-another-database-table-with-one-to-one-relationship-in-django-d/73759512#73759512)

The answer works the first time when a new record is being created. However, it fails to work the second time `profile()` is run because there is already an existing record.

How do I modify `profile()` such that a new record will be created if there is no existing record and an update will be made if the record already exists?

I am using Django v4, python v3.9, sqlite database on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django's [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) Model method, leaving rest of the logics untouched.

```py
 user_computed_info_instance, created  = UserComputedInfo.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user.id)
```

It'll create the object first time but will get the existing object next time for the same `id`.

Comment: Thanks but I got an error type object 'UserComputedInfo' has no attribute 'get_or_create'. I wonder if it's caused by the the way this method is being called.

Comment: @user3848207 My Bad, it should have been referenced by `objects` attribute.